# Xcode ipa output has bug while in xcode build doesn't

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

When I build my app on my iPhone in **Xcode** there's no problem at all but when I get **IPA** output(ad-hoc) it seems one of my buttons which I used an third-party library (ANLongTapButton) for that doesn't work well and it crashes. 
While I was getting IPA output I made sure that library is added.

what's wrong?!!

[image]
[image]

Comment: So there are several things you could check. Starting with the most likely: which build *configuration* is used for your "run" build and your adhoc build? Are different configs used? If so: do these build configurations have different settings that could influence something? For example code optimization *can* be a reason.

Comment: @JanBrinker i unchecked all checkboxes of optimizations. just add hoc and next ..u need a picture to see what i did?

Comment: it could be several reasons, optimisations are just one of them. The question about the build configurations remain. Do you use different build configurations for running and building adhoc?

Comment: @JanBrinker my build config is xcode default .. no idea about that...but when i want to have a adhoc distribution i just pick that option (addHoc) ...as that pictues added to question

Comment: in that case I think it's likely to be a bug in the Library you are using.

Comment: @JaneBrinker hmm.i think so too..i'm writing that button by my custom class :(

Comment: By default, normal build and addhoc build configurations are different. Go to Build setting tab and try to set all setting same for debug and release configuration and try again.

Comment: @LebRon yes they are different. But with the default setting this should not happen if the Pod was bug-free.